# C# Windows Forms - Banco de Dados Integrado

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, aplicação-desktop

Vou desenvolver uma aplicação Desktop, e essa aplicação vai fazer acesso a Banco de Dados Local, minha dúvida é:

Se eu fizer uma aplicação que acessa o SQL Server normalmente, quando eu gerar a versão release, eu vou ter que instalar o SQL Server no meu cliente também? ou é possível que o banco de dados venha junto com a aplicação e eu não precise instalar nada no cliente?

Comment: Sim, vai ter que instalar uma versão de SQL Server(Client) no cliente, e essa versão pode ir junto com a aplicação, depende do instalador que você gerar

Comment: Entendi! Obrigado!

Comment: Da uma pesquisada por CLICK ONCE https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-BR/library/t71a733d.aspx

Comment: Gabriel, se haverá banco de dados no computador cliente, então terá que instalar o SQL Server no computador, pois o SQL Server funciona como um serviço (exceto LocalDB). // No desenvolvimento está utilizando LocalDB ou Express?

Comment: José, eu estou usando o LocalDB